# Highcharts, how to fill in x-axis labels when datapoints don't exist

Tags: highcharts

I was wondering if there are any missing years in between the min and max, that those would be normally populated as well (for example 2012-2017, if there are only 2012 and 2017 datapoints, to still show 2015 or so in the middle on the x-axis).

Thanks a bunch! Let me know if it's unclear and I can put together a JSFiddle.

Comment: It depends on your dataset, do you use `categories` or `datetime` axis? For categorized axis, you need to fill all categories, for a `datetime` axis, it should work out of the box: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b1ys3gcz/

Comment: thanks pawel. datetime axis. hmm so the only way is to have actual null values for data points in there. i can't just have one point as 2012 and the other point as 2017 and expect the x-axis to have years filled out in between?

Comment: You can, still use `datetime` axis: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b1ys3gcz/1/

Comment: Ahh I noticed that having breaks even with an empty array was causing that to happen. Thanks for that! I'll have to thoroughly check my properties next time and compare with the examples.